# Why counter does not change in code bellow? How React hooks work then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to create a function like a React hook which will have inside variable and a function to change that variable. For reason unknown for me counter variable stays 0 even after function setCounter execute.

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  function setCounter() {
    console.log(count); // 0
    count += 1;
    console.log(count); // 1
  }
  console.log(count); // 0
  return {
    count,
    setCounter,
  };
}

const { count, setCounter } = makeCounter();
setCounter(); 
console.log(count); // 0
```

Comment: You don't have a render function? Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJP1E-Y-xyo to see a basic example of how hooks work under the hood

Comment: No, this isn't React code, it's pure JS. And my question is why it's not working in pure JS

Comment: If you actually watch the video they do not use react. They also show how to see updates

Comment: The issue you’re seeing is explained at 07:31

Comment: @evolutionxbox very cool video, thanks for sharing